# Can I use array in the LINQ where expression?

Tags: c#, linq

Would it be possible to use something like `.Where(u => u.License_ID == ID)` with ID being an array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the array contains custom objects, you could always write an extension method like

```
Equals(this Array[] _Array)
```

And define in there what are the requirements for equality.
Then your code becomes:

```
.Where(u => u.License_ID.Equals(ID))
```

And it would be highly reusable =)

Comment: This won't work if it's a query that is going to be translated to SQL. And it's confusing naming, that one item does not equal the whole array.

Comment: It's just an example so that he gets the point, not production code!

Answer (score 3):

The code

```
Where(u => IDs.Contains(u.License_ID))
```

could work, but it depends on your database provider whether it supports that. If this is not a database query, but LINQ to objects, it will certainly work.